# how to set the grid depth in achartengine android?

Tags: android, grid, achartengine

I have to plot ecg waves and I have used achartengine as library to plot.It works perfect :) 
Now I wanted to set the background so that I get a millimeterpaper as a normal ecg paper.
I have tried to get it but I could not! Can someone give tipps how I can proceed!!
I'm using Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 with 1280 x 800 Pixel.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AChartEngine builtin grid. To enable it:

```
renderer.setGridEnabled(true);
```

Please note that the grid lines are drawn from the labels points. So, you will have to tweak the number of labels you need:

```
renderer.setXLabels(approximateNumberOfXAxisLabels);
renderer.setYLabels(approximateNumberOfYAxisLabels);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I've done it and it works very well, but I wanted to ask if it's possible to do that without showing the values of each label!!
or how can I set my grid, so that I get it small as the millimeter paper!!

Comment: They are currently being displayed together.

Comment: Not sure I remember well, but I think you can do: renderer.setShowLabels(false);